# Closest number in a list

Tags: python, list

Given a list of integers, I need to find the closests numbers to each other inside the list

```
>> [1,9,5,45,80,2]
>> closest(lst)
>> 1,2
```

Is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: Google searching "find the two closest numbers in a list" yields lots of results, by the way. It's typically O(n^2) time.

Comment: If you ask without trying, you may regret losing all the fun :o)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831127/finding-the-two-closest-numbers-in-a-list-using-sorting

Answer (score 1):

- Sort the list
- Subtract adjacent elements
- Take the minimum of those differences